# Shared folder permissions in Vagrant 1.1.5

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, laravel, vagrant, laravel-3

Trying to set up a little Vagrant development environment right now using the Laravel framework and need to make my /vagrant/storage/views folder writeable, but I cannot get the permissions on the folder to change no matter what!

I have done:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /vagrant/storage/views
```

...and still am left with rwxr-xr-x permissions on that folder afterwards. I can change permissions of files, but not folders within my /vagrant folder.

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox provider (the default)? Maybe it's related to their shared folder mechanism..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, the problem was that I was trying to change the permissions on the shared folder from within the virtual machine. As soon as I just changed the permissions on my host copy of the folder, it propagated through to the guest machine's copy of the folder just fine.

Comment: This doesn't do it for me unfortunately ... It keeps complaining about not being able to write sessions in the storage folder. Any ideas?

Comment: What permissions do you have on the host folder and what do they show up as on the guest machine?

Comment: Started working eventually ... Don't even remember what I did. Thx! :)

Comment: @ARW : You seriously saved me eventually. I had spend my whole day. End of the day, I came to figure out from you that permission should be given to host copy folder rather than folder in my virtual box. I was really tired and almost giving up Vagrant ;). Thanks ARW.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this solution. I though I's share for Vagrant 1.6.3

`config.vm.synced_folder "LOCAL FOLDER", "/var/www", mount_options: ["dmode=777","fmode=666"]`

LOCAL FOLDER = I put my site in a folder. Since the folder is in the same directory as my Vagrantfile I dont have a slash before or trailing.

/var/www = this is where my site lives on the guest.

mount_options = i had trouble with some -R permissions and such - this seemed to fix it.